# Tmux, Vim - Double quotes & comments are invisible(hidden)

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm using vim in tmux. When i use quotes to enclose some string the quotes can't see its' looks like invisible.
Same thing with all the comments in the file they can't see they are invisible or hidden. How can i fix this anyone know please?

Answer (score 0):

I use tmux and vim,too.The problem maybe caused by your color scheme and backgroud.

First,you can add config like this:`set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` to your tmux config file and reload tmux.

If this didn't work,you can change your vim color scheme and backgroud which is usually defined in your `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your vim colorscheme while vim is running:

```
:colorscheme darkblue 
:colorscheme morning
```